# Select Range Of DateTimePicker not working properly

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Is there any default way in kendo DatePicker for ensuring  that To date is always greater than or equal to From date. [here is the code I've tried](http://jsfiddle.net/5bchz/58/):

My Range selection code:

```
function startChange() {
    var startDate = startdatetimepicker.value(),
            endDate = enddatetimepicker.value();

    if (startDate) {
        startDate = new Date(startDate);
        startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate());
        enddatetimepicker.min(startDate);
    } else if (endDate) {
        startdatetimepicker.max(new Date(endDate));
    } else {
        endDate = new Date();
        startdatetimepicker.max(endDate);
        enddatetimepicker.min(endDate);
    }
}

function endChange() {
    var endDate = enddatetimepicker.value(),
            startDate = startdatetimepicker.value();

    if (endDate) {
        endDate = new Date(endDate);
        endDate.setDate(endDate.getDate());
        startdatetimepicker.max(endDate);
    } else if (startDate) {
        enddatetimepicker.min(new Date(startDate));
    } else {
        endDate = new Date();
        startdatetimepicker.max(endDate);
        enddatetimepicker.min(endDate);
    }
}
```

I am getting this error-->  "property 'value' od object 3 is not a function"

Comment: No, there is not such out-of-the-box validation, you need to implement it. Check `http://demos.kendoui.com/web/datepicker/rangeselection.html`

Comment: ya i tried with above code but it's not working.http://jsfiddle.net/5bchz/58/

Comment: Can any one help me please i didn't find any solution for out-of-the-box validation.

Comment: Just a clue to make you think (I hope this helps you on how to debug a program)... What is `startdatetimepicker`? Where you define it? Is it an `object` with a `value()` method? Are you sure? When you copy you should understand what you are copying...

Comment: ya as per my knowledge object means we can pass anything  to method,  so here i passed "id" of datetimepicker (startdatetimepicker) to value() method. if i am wrong can you please clarify me if you dont mind.

Comment: :-) `startdatepicker` is an HTML input object and there is no `value` method but `property`. So you should use: `startdatetimepicker.value`

Comment: The example were you copied it from used a variable that correspond to a Kendo UI Date Time Picker...

Comment: after passing value as a property i am got one more error that  "Property 'min' of object #<HTMLInputElement> is not a function "      I think this "min" is property  in value() method so it's error or any other reason?

Comment: Still confused with with HTML object and Kendo UI objects! Check here  http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/5bchz/72/

Comment: Ya thank you onabai it's working but here one more issue is when i am enter the first date in grid "18-02-13 19:54:13" it's not filtering but when i am enter 19-02-13 20:55:20 it's filter "gt" but in my condition i have given "ge" .actually this is not related to above queston but previously it's work fine but now it's not working properly can you check it once please please  http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/5bchz/72/

Comment: Do your work with @kvs? are you duplicating questions?

Comment: no onabi i dont know about @kvs. no i am not duplicating questions.while checking my code i got above isuue so i posted comment

Comment: He/She is asking the same type of questions with very (too) similar code (!!!)

Comment: There was a typo error when setting the event handler for date picker changes for the end date. I think that now it is fixed: http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/5bchz/81/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `startdatepicker` is an `HTML input object` and there is no `value` method but `property`. So you should use: `startdatetimepicker.value`.

Nevertheless I recommend changing using the Kendo UI Date Time Picker as:

```js
function startChange() {
    var startDate = k_startdatetimepicker.value(),
            endDate = k_enddatetimepicker.value();

    if (startDate) {
        startDate = new Date(startDate);
        startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate());
        k_enddatetimepicker.min(startDate);
    }
    else if (endDate) {
        k_startdatetimepicker.max(new Date(endDate));
    }
    else {
        endDate = new Date();
        k_startdatetimepicker.max(endDate);
        k_enddatetimepicker.min(endDate);
    }
}

function endChange() {
    var endDate = k_enddatetimepicker.value(),
            startDate = k_startdatetimepicker.value();
    console.log(endDate, startDate);

    if (endDate) {
        endDate = new Date(endDate);
        endDate.setDate(endDate.getDate());
        k_startdatetimepicker.max(endDate);
    }
    else if (startDate) {
        k_enddatetimepicker.min(new Date(startDate));
    }
    else {
        endDate = new Date();
        k_startdatetimepicker.max(endDate);
        k_enddatetimepicker.min(endDate);
    }
}
```

where `k_startdatetimepicker` and `k_enddatetimepicker` are:

```js
var k_startdatetimepicker = $("#startdatetimepicker").kendoDateTimePicker({
    change: startChange,
    showSecond: true,
    dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
    timeFormat: "HH:mm:ss",
    format: "dd-MM-yy HH:mm:ss"
}).data("kendoDateTimePicker");


var k_enddatetimepicker = $("#enddatetimepicker").kendoDateTimePicker({
    change: endChange,
    showSecond: true,
    dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
    timeFormat: "HH:mm:ss",
    format: "dd-MM-yy HH:mm:ss"
}).data("kendoDateTimePicker");
```

Running JSfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/5bchz/81/)

Comment: Thank you so much onabai and the way your are helped me is really great that again i will gone through kendo documents again